# Make a panel with values visible when I press a radiobutton

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a uibuttongroup with radio buttons defined in it. I have uipanels defined with their corresponding properties. What I want to do is to be able to click one radio button and have one uipanel appear, and then click my other radio button to have the other uipanel appear. Here are snippets of my code:

```
operation_type_1 = uibuttongroup(S.Test, 'Title', 'Operation Type', 'position', [0 0.3 panel_w/2 0.15]);
uicontrol('Parent',operation_type_1, 'Style', 'radiobutton',...
               'String', 'invisible',...
               'position', [0 0 0 0], 'Tag', 'invisibutton');

uicontrol('Parent',operation_type_1,'Style','radiobutton',...
               'String', 'Time Operation',...
               'Position', 100*[0.1 flooring(3.5, 'tp') 1.2 0.15], 'Tag', 'timeop1');

uicontrol('Parent',operation_type_1,'Style','radiobutton',...
               'String', 'Volume Operation',...
               'Position', 100*[0.1 flooring(2.5, 'tp') 1.2 0.15], 'Tag', 'volumeop1');
```

This defines my button group and the two radio buttons.

Then I have code which creates a volume panel:

[image: Volume Panel]

As well as a Time Panel:

[image: Time Panel]

These are in the same position. What I want is to be able to click on the "Time Operation" radio button and have the time panel be visible, and when I click on the "Volume Operation" radio button, the volume panel is visible.

I've tried doing switch case statements. I don't get errors, but I don't get results either. For example, my case statements for the time and volume panels are:

```
switch str
    case 'timeop1'
    if U.Value; S.result_panel_time1.Visible = 'On';
    else S.result_panel_time1.Visible = 'Off'; 
    end

    case 'volumeop1'
    if U.Value; S.result_panel_volume1.Visible = 'On';
    else S.result_panel_volume1.Visible = 'Off';
end
```

How do I get this to work? I'm not using GUIDE, just coding a MATLAB GUI.

**UPDATE**

I've tried implementing the callback suggested below, but I get a "Function definition is misplaced or improperly nested." error. I use the following function:

```
function button_callback(U, varargin{2})
    switch get(get(operation_type_1, 'SelectedObject'), 'Tag')
        case 'timeop1'
            if U.Value; S.result_panel_time1.Visible = 'On';
            else S.result_panel_time1.Visible = 'Off'; 
            end
        case 'volumeop1'
            if U.Value; S.result_panel_volume1.Visible = 'On';
            else S.result_panel_volume1.Visible = 'Off'; 
            end  
    end
end
```

And I've added the callbacks "...'callback', {@pb_call, S}" to my timeop1 and volumeop1. (Because all of the other function I have are in a .m file called pb_call.m). The function appears to be nested fine but the error points at the exact one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you did not define [callback](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) for your RadioButton. For example, set callback for volumeop1:

```
uicontrol('Parent',operation_type_1,'Style','radiobutton',...
               'String', 'Volume Operation',...
               'Position', 100*[0.1 0.3 1.2 0.15], 'Tag', 'volumeop1', ...
               'Callback', @switchPanel);
```

Then in function switchPanel, you will set corresponding panel visible, while set others invisible.

This is trying to answer your questions, but it seems to me what you want is [uitab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitab.html).

Comment: I've updated my question with how I've implemented your suggestion. Can you suggest a fix? If this fixes it I'll gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My partner ended up fixing it:

The callback was {callback, S} and S, U, and str were:

```
S = varargin{3}; %main figure handle
U = varargin{1}; %current uicontrol
str = char(U.String);
```

The problem occurred in the radiobutton creation, since the result panels were being created after the radiobuttons could be triggered, thus nothing was made invisible/visible and an error would occur.

However, it would be highly convenient if callbacks could affect all GUI parts, not just previously defined ones. I've tried using guidata in the past, but I had to use other, less straighforward methods to accomplish my goals. I'll try using working samples and building upon those in the future, but currently I am working on another part of the project and will get back to that later.

But using either guidata/setappdata or something related would work here as well as my own solution, which is making sure that the objects you are trying to change are already defined before the button triggering the callback.

(He also posted this answer to where I asked this same question in MATLAB Answers.)